# Anyway to clone mesh from one object to another?

Tags: modifiers, geometry

Is there anyway to clone a mesh type to another object? For example, I have a mesh generated from a 360 photo, but is not a procedural texture or material that's been applied. The actual geometry comes from the photo scan itself, which was then turned into an FBX and imported into Blender. Can I somehow copy this geometry to the newly created top part of my object? Or turn it into a texture/material to use on the top object? Currently the top is a plane I created and beveled but has no type of geometry that matches the main model.

Edit: I do am not looking to just grab the verts and paste them somewhere else on the model. Can I create some sort of geometry brush based off a certain area to re-apply on others?

[image]

Comment: Hello :). To turn geometry into a texture look up *texture baking*. There's plenty of posts about it here on SE and videos on YT.

Comment: Hello, thank you; I wasn't looking to bake any textures. I wanted to grab a certain part of the actual geometry and copy it to another part of the object, far before any textures are completed, as described above. @JachymMichal